# SWRevealViewController - know which ViewController is displayed

Tags: iphone, ios, uigesturerecognizer, exc-bad-access, uipangesturerecognizer

I am using the SWRevealViewController plugin (https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController) to have drawer-like transitions in my iOS app.

I added a panGestureRecognizer to my view to allow the user to drag the right ViewController to hide the left VC:

```
[self.view addGestureRecognizer: self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
```

Now i'd like to detect when the right VC has been dragged to trigger an animation, so basically I just want to find a way to automatically know which VC is displayed.

So far I have tried to bind an event to self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer with this code:

```
 [self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer addTarget:self action:@selector(PanGestureEnded:)];
```

And then do this:

```
-(void)PanGestureEnded:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture{
    if (gesture.state==UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        //some code here
    }
}
```

But my app always crashes and I gest a exc_bad_access error. So I enabled NSZombies and I get the following error message:

```
 -[TabBarViewController PanGestureEnded:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xc1ad890
```

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Many thanks

Comment: anybody to help me on this please?

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same error today when trying to bind an action to self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer also.

I cannot fix the error. Instead, I set the current controller as the delegate of revealViewController, and call the delegate method:

```
- (void)revealControllerPanGestureBegan:(SWRevealViewController *)revealController
```

and perform my action in the above method.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same issue recently.

I was able to solve it by updating SWRevealViewController project to its latest release and instead of using the segue connection as "reveal view controller" (which is now deprecated) I'm using "reveal view controller push controller".